# Unable to click pagination of grid to verify certain grid values

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm using the below method to verify certain table data, in all the pages of the table. I have tried all the possibilities, could anyone share your thoughts on this.

The below code is my page,

```
this.isApplicationPresentUsingName = function (name) {

    return this.pgnumCount.count().then(function(num){
        if (num > 0) {
            console.log(num);
            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                return this.pgnumCount.filter(function(pg){
                    pg.getText().then(function(text){
                       return text.toString()===i.toString();
                   }).then(function(number){
                       number.click();
                }).then(function(){
                this.checkApplication(name).then(function (found) {
                    console.log("Text1");
                return found.length > 0;});
                });
            });
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Pagination not exists');
        }
    });
});
```

> this.checkApplication = function (text) { return element.all(by.cssContainingText("#application-auth-list-2 tbody tr td:first-child", text)); };
>
> this.pgnumCount=$$('a.ui-paginator-page');

I'm calling it in my spec as below,

> expect(appAuth.isApplicationPresentUsingName(applicationName)).toBeFalsy();

I'm facing the below issue,

> Failed: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

But i can able to get the page number as 3 exactly the match in console.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I will explain how your code will be executed.

```
this.isApplicationPresentUsingName = function (name) {

return this.pgnumCount.count().then(function (num) {

    //You will get the total number of pages

    if (num > 0) {
        console.log(num);
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            //below statement will throw an error because 
            // `this` refers to current function scope.
            return this.pgnumCount.filter(function (pg) {
                // return statement is missing.
                // so the filter wont work
                pg.getText().then(function (text) {
                    // value of i will always equals to num
                    // because this code will be executed asynchronously
                    // you need to use `closure` to get correct value of i
                    return text.toString() === i.toString();
                }).then(function (number) {
                    number.click();
                }).then(function () {
                    this.checkApplication(name).then(function (found) {
                        console.log("Text1");
                        return found.length > 0;
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Pagination not exists');
    }
});
}
```

So your actual code should look something like,

```
this.isApplicationPresentUsingName = function (name) {
//save the reference of `this` to a local variable.
var self = this;

function recursiveSearch(currentPage, totalPage) {
    if (currentPage < totalPage) {
         //if current page is less total page
         // click the current page number
         self.pgnumCount.get(currentPage).click();
            // check if name is present in current page
            return self.checkApplication(name).then(function (found) {
                //if name is present in current page, return true.
                if (found) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                   //if name is not present in current page, 
                   // we need to again click next page and check if it is present
                    return recursiveSearch(index + 1, totalPage)
                }
            });
        }     else {
             //after checking for the name in all pages
             // return false because the name is not present in any of the page.
            return false;
        }
    }

    //get the total page number and recursively check if the name is present in each page.
    return this.pgnumCount.count().then(function (totalCount) {
        //start with page 0 till total number of pages    
        return recursiveSearch(0, totalCount);
    });

};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan, but still I'm facing some issues. I'm using **`this.checkApplication = function (text) { return element.all(by.cssContainingText("#application-auth-list-2 tbody tr td:first-child", text)); };`** , it was working fine previously, but in this method, it should return false, since I'm givng false name, but it returns true. I'm wondering how it is happening

Comment: Thanks, i have changed the condition for if and now its working fine